# Filter the referenced property in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a `StateMachine` table having all the states in a key, value pair model, like:

stateId   StateName

1       INITIATED
  2       STARTED

```
class DeviceStates  {

    private int deviceStateId;
    private String deviceStateName;

}
```

I have referred this StateMachine table in Device table

```
class Device   {

   private Integer deviceId;
   private String serialNum;
   private Date lastModifiedDate;
   private DeviceStates deviceStatesByDeviceStateId;

}
```

I have to filter out few DeviceStates from Device table for search. 
Please help me how to write the Criteria with which I

> should be able to get a filter out a few DeviceStates from Device

.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Aren't your Device and DeviceStates classes mapped?

Comment: yeah, it mapped in hbm.xml files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Device.class, "device");
c.createAlias("deviceStatesByDeviceStateId", "state");
c.add(Restrictions.in("state.id", setOfAcceptedStateIds));
```

Your code would be much more readable if the class was named `DeviceState` (since each instance of the class is one and only one state), and if the field was named `state` instead of `deviceStatesByDeviceStateId`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll follow afterwards.